# Using Custom Meta Data in wp_nav_menu()

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using [`wp_nav_menu()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) in order to call a navigation menu on the left hand side. However, instead of page names I wish to list custom meta data as the menu links to each page. I have the meta boxes set up but am having an issue calling them in to the wp_nav_menu(). The meta boxes are saving the data correctly etc.

Meta boxes are called `meta_box_text` within the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

[`wp_nav_menu()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) echoes (or optionally returns) HTML code for the menu. You want to access data related to the data the menu is built from, so you are already too late to do that.

Instead copy the code of the function, give it another name and modify it to suit your needs. You can then use your function instead in a similar fashion but with your added features.

Alternatively you can reverse-engineer the code only as well and see if you can hook into some filters or actions to add your feature (instead of duplicating the code and modifying it).